# addresses in a 64-bit process on Linux

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit

I wrote a (to show the problem) a simple C-pgm which has a function func() in the source code and another function funcs() in a shared lib; the compilation is done with:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o libfuncs.so -m64 -g funcs.c
$ gcc -g -m64 -fPIC -o stack stack.c -L. -lfuncs
```

i.e. it's a 64-bit compiled phm and shared lib:

```
$ file stack libfuncs.so
stack:       ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.0.0, BuildID[sha1]=bf7a7e15181e110789a4ee0b237f3a8ec58d4823, not stripped
libfuncs.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=f1ffa166db952b92479c36169252e5ddff01e19e, not stripped
```

When I examine this with gdb I have the questions: Why the 64-bit addr `char *p` is shown as **0x400734** or after a malloc() as **0x602010**, I would expect 8 bytes as it is for the `char *p` in the shared lib, shown as **0x7ffff7bd9609**:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at stack.c:12
12         char *p = "hello";
(gdb) n
14         p = (char *) malloc(10);
(gdb) p p
$1 = 0x400734 "hello"
(gdb) n
16         func(p, "foo");
(gdb) p p
$2 = 0x602010 ""
(gdb) s
func (p=0x602010 "", s=0x40073a "foo") at stack.c:25
25         char *a = "bla";
(gdb) n
27      }
(gdb) p a
$3 = 0x40073e "bla"
(gdb) n
main () at stack.c:17
17         funcs(p, "foo");   // this is a shared lib
(gdb) s
funcs (a=0x602010 "", b=0x40073a "foo") at funcs.c:8
8           char *p = "bar";
(gdb) n
10      }
(gdb) p p
$4 = 0x7ffff7bd9609 "bar"
```

Comment: @guru 0x400734 is 8 bytes.

Comment: How can 0x400734 be 8 bytes? 0x0000000000400734 are 8 bytes.

Comment: so `0` is 0 bits always?

Comment: Two hex digits represent one byte (each nybble is 4 bits, which can contain numbers 0-15).

Comment: GDB formats the addresses as if by `%#llx`. The leading zeroes are omitted because they're zeroes. You ask why is the address not 8 bytes, and I say it is 8 bytes.

Comment: Your last comment about the GDB format and leading zeros is fine. Saying "0x400734 is 8 bytes" is just wrong. It represents three bytes and does not say anything about other bytes.

Comment: @guru Why do think that 0x400734  can't be the value of an 8 byte pointer? It is just  the leading zeros that isn't printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When code runs under gdb,  [address space layout randomization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is disabled for easier debugging and reproducibility. This makes it easier to pack all relevant allocation bits into the first 32 bit addresses.

There is nothing special about it, and with big-enough allocations you will start seeing higher addresses.

Try printing the pointers in the code, rather than in gdb, and see how it goes.

**Note**: assess space layout randomization does not necessarily mean that allocations can't reside in the lower 32 bit addresses, just that randomization takes part of the space. Also, it depends on the actual address randomization algorithm.

Comment: Although I agree that "[ASLR] does not necessarily mean that allocations can't reside in the lower 32 bit addresses," it does make such addresses unlikely.